# Highlight cell when hovered over

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I've already tried my best with the `Column Event` `onMouseEnter`.
But as the docs mention, events

> events [...] will receive some specific information

Source: https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/column-props.html#columnevents-object

There is no such thing as:

```
onMouseEnter: () => {
   cell.setStyling({backgroundColor: 'green'})
}
```

Right now I'm stuck at highlighting a cell hovered over.

Here's some example code: https://react-f1nw5e.stackblitz.io
With the given parameters I just don't see any option on how I could achieve a solution to my problem.

Could some of you please help me out of it? Thanks a lot!

Greets

Comment: You need to add the whole code if you want it debugged. You can create a StackBlitz for example that is much easier to debug and post the link here

Comment: @Ferie I just edited my post and added an example on StackBlitz.